# Questions about Mountain Lion breaking programming tools

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, migration, off-topic

OS X Mountain Lion was released a short while ago and as a result many people who upgraded are experiencing problems with their programming tools (see [osx-mountain-lion](/questions/tagged/osx-mountain-lion)).

What's the policy regarding these questions? On-topic? Off-topic? Migrate to Superuser or [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

Surely this depends. Developer tools are not on topic on Superuser or AskDifferent so should stay here as noted in the SO FAQ.

> software tools commonly used by programmers

Ones that re just running applications could be on topic for AskDifferent. I also would think that most are more on topic for Ask Different rather than Superuser - I think things get migrated more to Superuser because it is one of the 5 sites that show on the off topic dialog.

But it depends :) for example this [gatekeeper question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665386/os-x-10-8-gatekeeper-and-java-applets) starts by asking what is happeing and that really should be answered on AskDifferent but then asks about how to sign the code which is development an on topic on SO.

I am not certain where installing/building software should go as it is code related but not writing code.

Oh a general comment to those upgrading **ASSUME THINGS WILL BREAK** so either set up on a spare machine to test or wait for reports from others before upgrading if you have to have things working for an urgent deliverable. (If people did that many of the questions would not arise)

Comment: I could see even the Gatekeeper portion of the question you highlighted being on topic for Stack Overflow, because it is a technology that developers have to understand in order to make their applications compatible with it.